# How to stop RubyMine giving pathspec error on git commit

Tags: git, rubymine

When I try to commit changes to my project using the built-in RubyMine git | add and git | commit options I keep getting fatal errors like:

> Error:error: pathspec
>   'features/authentication/administrator_logs_in.feature' did not match
>   any file(s) known to git. error: pathspec
>   'features/authentication/modeller_logs_in.feature' did not match any
>   file(s) known to git. error: pathspec
>   'features/authentication/forecaster_logs_in.feature' did not match any
>   file(s) known to git. error: pathspec
>   'features/authentication/guest_logs_in.feature' did not match any
>   file(s) known to git. error: pathspec
>   'features/authentication/data_manager_logs_in.feature' did not match
>   any file(s) known to git.  during executing git commit --only -F
>   C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-6533175276977325116.txt
>   -- app/models/country.rb features/region_management/delete_region.feature
>   app/views/regions/new.html.haml
>   features/region_classifier_management/create_region_classifier.feature
>   .idea/tf.iml config/breadcrumbs.rb
>   app/controllers/countries_controller.rb

... and a whole load more like that. If I hit git | commit again it (usually) works just fine. What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tracked it down. Although the error report gave me paths like 'features/authentication/administrator_logs_in.feature', `git status` shows the offending path as 'features/Authentication/administrator_logs_in.feature' (different capitalisation). I'm on MS Windows, so they look the same to my system but apparently not to git. The version in the error report is the correct one.

I tried solving it using git to rename the files, but that was rejected because the destination file already existed so I had to use git to move the files to a new location, commit, then use git to move them back (with the correct capitalisation).